# Adding options to select field in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, forms, select

I am trying to add option fields to a select field, all within the same JavaScript like this:

```
function addRow() {

  var teeArray = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem("teeBoxes"));

  var table = document.createElement('tr');
  table.innerHTML = '<tr>\
    <td>\
      <select class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">';

      for(var i = 0; i < teeArray.length; i++){
        table.innerHTML += '<option value="foo">Foo '+i+'</option>'; 
      }


      table.innerHTML += '</select>\
    </td>\
    <td><input id="p1" name="p1" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md wField"></td>\
    <td><input id="p2" name="p2" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md wField"></td>\
    <td><input id="p3" name="p3" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md mField"></td>\
    <td><input id="p4" name="p4" type="number" placeholder="" class="form-control input-md mField"></td>\
  </tr>';

  document.getElementById('teeBody').appendChild(table);

}
```

This is not working as I thought... All option fields is added outside the `<select></select>` tags.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Whenever you stop adding to `innerHTML`, the browser will close any tags you haven't closed. Instead, either use DOM methods (like `createElement`) for all elements, or concatenate all of the strings at once and set `innerHTML` once. Note that you have `var table = document.createElement('tr');` which doesn't seem right...

Comment: `document.createElement('tr');` creates a `TableRowElement`, disregarding how bad the practice of manually composing HTML like that is, there's no need to add `<tr>` inside again.

Comment: @HereticMonkey fixed it by creating all as string forst and then adding it to the .innerHTML :-) Thanks!

Comment: Feel free to accept the duplicate mark.